# How to ignore the warning c4090

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

All, I was using the [RtlZeroMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to empty the memory in my project. But when I build the project I got a warning says `warning C4090: 'function' : different 'const' qualifiers` for below code.

```
RtlZeroMemory(&copiedRelatedObj, FltObjects->Size);
```

After researching, I found it doesn't matter with this warning, But It stop the build process . How I ignore or disable this warning ? thanks.

Comment: It does matter, you are attempting to modify a const object. Trust your compiler and fix your code. If you post the code then I'm sure someone will help you fix it.

Comment: How is copiedRelatedObj declared? And what is `FltObjects`? Rather than suppressing the warning, understand it first.

Comment: @john thanks , you are right , I forgot to check the type define of copiedRelatedObj. It is modified by `const`. I had change its type. thank you David, I already fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio you can disable warning using `#pragma`

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4090 )
```

Or you can do it for all your project via

> *Project Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *Advanced* -> *Disable Specific Warnings*

**You should try to fix your code instead of ignoring this warning.**

You should read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512222/is-it-a-good-idea-to-eliminate-compiler-warnings) and [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/compiler_warnings.html) about compiler warnings.